# Space between ActionBar and ListView Rows

Tags: android-layout, listview, android-listview, android

I have a ListView in a LinearLayout. I want to have space between actionbar and my first item of listview like YouTube App:
[image]

to getting this result, I've tried padding and margin in order for LinearLayout and ListView, but when user scroll ListView, items should goes beyond of Actionbar BUT!! as you can see in my result image, items start disappearing by space from top edge! ( space is my padding or margin that was set for listview or linearlayout )

Is anybody there that know how can handle this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Try using a header which should be blank...

Comment: @vwvwvwvwvwvwvwvwvw Header for ListView?

Comment: yes listview with header

Comment: @vwvwvwvwvwvwvwvwvw Okay thanks, I'm going to try it

Comment: I think Youtube show TextView in Header of ListView.

Comment: @VivekWarde Which  header did you use it ?, I have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

all you need to do is add a textview to the xml above the listview. Should look like something below:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.90" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="422dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```